# Is there a way to get the status of a specific thread executed via PXLongOperation() outside of the current BLC?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to create an INTransfer and release it after an INReceipt is made on the Release action within the Move page of the Manufacturing Module. I've been getting an error stating that no inventory is available, but it is not consistent. After doing some digging, I believe it is because the release of the receipt is not finished before I execute my call to INDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(). I found that if I add a thread sleep, it will execute no problem every time, but I don't want to force the user to wait X seconds every time they execute that release. Is there a way I can check if the release process thread is complete for the INReceipt and wait if it is not to execute my release?

The problems I am having is that I don't know if there is a way to grab the ID of the PXLongOperation thread that is executing the INReceipt release function. If there is, I know there is a way to execute a PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion() function I can execute. I believe I would execute that right before calling my PXLongOperation if I am able to get the threadID.

Answer (score 0):

Consider usage of IPXCustomInfo. [Here](https://blog.zaletskyy.com/how-to-react-on-clicking-on-abort-button-in-acumatica-processing-screen) I've described how to react on clicking on Abort, but also you can consider how to add reaction on Completed and InProcess cases:

```
case PXLongRunStatus.Completed:
            SomeReactionOnCompleted();
            break;

        case PXLongRunStatus.InProcess:
            SomeReactionOnInProcess();
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
string JobKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
PXLongOperation.StartOperation(JobKey, () => MQICCreatePOFromSOProcess.PerformDocumentCreation(new List<SOOrder>() { Base.CurrentDocument.Current }));
// Need to wait for completion, to let user know which document was created/updated
PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(JobKey);
```